# I would like to make a veto map list in order to choose a map for scrimming?

Tags: python

Im new i guess and havent done python in like 6 months. I want a list of game maps (from overwatch), and then ask the user to remove a map from the list and then ask again until only 5 maps remain. Here is what I have and i honestly have no idea what im doing.

```
Hanamura = 1
Horizon_Lunar_Colony = 2
Temple_of_Anubis = 3
Volskaya_Industries = 4
Dorado = 5
Junkertown = 6
Rialto = 7
Route_66 = 8
Gibraltar = 9
Blizzard_World = 10
Eichenwalde = 11
Hollywood = 12
Kings_row = 13
Numbani = 14
Ilios = 15
Lijiang = 16
Nepal = 17
Oasis = 18
# (Hanamura, Horizon_Luner_Colony, Temple_of_Anubis, Volskaya_Industries, 
Dorado, Junkertown, Rialto, Route_66, Gibraltar, Blizzard_World, Eichenwalde, 
Hollywood, Kings_row, Numbani, Ilios, Lijiang, Nepal, Oasis)
# (Hanamura =  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,15, 16, 17, 18)
print ('Hanamura0 \nHorizon_Lunar_Colony1 \nTemple_of_Anubis2 
\nVolskaya_Industries3 \nDorado4 \nJunkertown5 \nRialto6 \nRoute_66_7 
\nGibraltar8 \nBlizzard_World9 \nEichenwalde10 \nHollywood11 \nKings_row12 
\nNumbani13 \nIlios14 \nLijiang15 \nNepal16 \nOasis 17\n')
p = 1
numbofitems = 18

if numbofitems >= 5:
    x =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
    x.remove(input())
    print(x)
    numbofitems - p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
maps =  ['Hanamura',
     'Horizon_Lunar_Colony',
     'Temple_of_Anubis',
     'Volskaya_Industries',
     'Dorado',
     'Junkertown',
     'Rialto',
     'Route_66',
     'Gibraltar',
     'Blizzard_World',
     'Eichenwalde',
     'Hollywood',
     'Kings_row',
     'Numbani',
     'Ilios',
     'Lijiang',
     'Nepal',
     'Oasis']

num = 5

while len(maps) >= num:
    print("Map list:\n")
    for m in maps: # Iterates on the maps list
        print(m)
    print("\n")

    to_remove = input("Remove a map: ")

    try: # Try to remove selected map from the list
        maps.remove(to_remove)
        print("\n{} map removed!\n".format(to_remove))
    except: # An exception occurs if it's not in the list
        print("\nSelected map not in the list!\n")
        pass

print("{} in the list!\n".format(num))
```